# Even the gevent and monkey patching added top of the imports its giving error

Tags: grequests

Even the gevent and monkey patching added top of the imports its giving error: MonkeyPatchWarning: Patching more than once will result in the union of all True parameters being patched curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False) please anyone help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gevent` gives this warning because the monkey patch was repeatedly applied. detail: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/monkey.py#L1021
You can check if this is the case with your code or third-party dependencies.

ps： `grequests` has patched monkey patch in https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py#L21